# Connect Loopback4 with neo4j using looback-connector-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, loopbackjs, loopback4

I've a backend service in Loopback4 and want to use graph database (Neo4j) using [loopback-connector-neo4j-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-connector-neo4j-graph).

But when I try to fetch the data. It gives me timeout error.
I'm trying to connect using HTTP protocol.

**Datasource config**

```json
{
  "port": 33729,
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "name": "db",
  "connector": "neo4j-graph",
  "hostname": "ipaddress"
}
```

**Controller**

```js
@get('/neo4js')
async find(): Promise<any> {
  return this.neo4JRepository.execute("MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100", (err: any, results: any) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    return results;
  }
}
```

Could somebody please help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you share some configuration & code please?

Comment: This question has been [posted](https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1608619530242100) in the LoopBack community Slack channel and may have been answered there. Check the loopback.io website for a link to join the Slack channel.

Comment: LoopBack 4's [.execute](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.execute.html) function does not take in a callback function. Could you check to make sure that it's being utilized correctly? Try using `lb4 datasource` to generate the boilerplate code then replace the connector if necessary.

Comment: From the Slack thread:

Hey @Rifa Achrinza, I was trying to connect to neo4j sandbox. But then I thought to install it in local and tried to connect to local db. It worked in local. There might be some issues connecting to sandbox.